# Use subdomain name in my PHP code?

Tags: php, url

First of all, what's the difference between:

> www.domain.com

and

> domain.com

Should I pay attention to this when I do the coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would highly recommend to use relative paths.

This has many advantages, for instance:

- Paths are shorter
- If you want to move to a different domainname you don't have to check through thousands of codelines

In general there IS a difference between: www.domain.com and domain.com. The "www" prefix is nothing more than an ordinary subdomain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain

Comment: what is relative paths?? is it the "../folder/file.php"??

Comment: Yes                    [Please enter at least 15 characters.]

Answer (score 3):

```
domain.com
```

Is the registered domain and

```
www.domain.com
```

Is a sub-domain of `domain.com`, they are not alway the same. Most web sites will set up their webserver to redirect domain.com to www.doamin.com or vice versa.

Depending on the DNS Zone file configuration sub-domains can point to different IP addresses (possibly different physical servers).

```
example.com.  A     10.0.0.1              ; ip address for "example.com"
ns            A     10.0.0.2              ; ip address for "ns.example.com"
www           CNAME ns                    ; "www.example.com" is an alias for   "ns.example.com"
wwwtest       CNAME www                   ; "wwwtest.example.com" is another alias for "www.example.com"
mail          A     10.0.0.3              ; ip address for "mail.example.com", any MX record host must be
```

Taken form Wikipedia - [DNS Zone File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file)

Answer (score 0):

Relative urls arnt the best idea. its a good idea to have one constant hold the value for a relative url and the rest to be static